# 403 при парсинге CURLом

Tags: php, curl

Парсю страницы госзакупок, использую CURL, после некоторого промежутка времени сайт не пускает, выдает 403 ошибку. Можно ли как то избежать этого? Может использовать не CURL, а что то другое? Про ftp госзакупок знаю, именно таким образом мне нужно в учебных целях

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    $uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PMBC=96152e8e9a0168a731539c5e52c6b39a; PHPSESSID=jl0i13pn3157qca807jgp0jqa7; ServerName=WoW+Circle+3.3.5a+x5; serverId=1");
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Возможно Вы слишком часто обращались к ресурсу и он посчитал Ваш запрос опасным, теперь отбрасывает, если ранее удавалось получить ответ 200 и инфо, попробуйте добавить таймауты или использовать прокси

Comment: Вы можете попробовать, конечно, с помощью сокетов делать это (будет немного дольше curl). Если у обрабатывающего сервера есть какой-либо ограничитель по времени, вы можете делать задержки между выполнениями curl

Comment: используя sleep()?

Comment: @Александр вполне